# How do I populate an array using user input in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, user-input

I'm very new to Swift and I'm trying to make a finance manager app. It's pretty straightforward and I know what I want to do, it's just actually executing it that's been tricky for me. For now I have:

```
var income = [3000, 1000, 250, 200]
var expenses = [3000, 500, 150]

let sumOfIncome = income.reduce(0, +)
let sumOfExpenses = expenses.reduce(0, +)
let balance = sumOfIncome - sumOfExpenses
print("Balance: \(balance)")
```

In this code I get the total income for the month and the total expenses for the month and subtract them to get the balance. Now instead of writing out what the income and expenses are in the code, I want to have user input populate the array so it can be different every time (also, is it possible for the user to input as many integer values as they want? Whether it's 5 values or 50?). How can I do this?

Comment: What user input? Do you want to write an iOS or macOS app? Either way, do some research on the topic and come back when you have a more specific question. Your question in its current form clearly lacks research effort and is too broad as well.

Comment: You can use a tabBarController and add 3 tabs. One for income, one for expenses and another one for summary. For the income and expenses just add a table view controller with a button to add a new item to that table view controller data source.

Comment: Thanks Leo! I'm going to try that out